# why does this array throw an error when useState has default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure it out why this code throws an error when trying to get the length of the array or even when trying to render on JSX, it throws the same error.

Why does the state [postData] not use the default value before sending a get request to update it with the new data?

Pretty much, I want my initial Data to be default, until I send the request or use the setPostData(dataRequest). What am I doing wrong? Thanks

ERROR: ViewPost.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';
import StateContext from '../StateContext';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import iconSet from '../selection.json';
import IcomoonReact, { iconList } from 'icomoon-react';

function ViewPost() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState([
        {
            _id: '...',
            username: '...',
            avatar: '...',
            date: '...',
            text: '...',
            image: '...',
            likes: [],
            hearts: [],
            retweet: [],
            user: '...',
            isFollowing: 'false',
            isVerified: 'false',
            comments: [{ test: 'test' }],
            name: '...',
            surname: '...',
        },
    ]);

    console.log(postData.comments.length) // throws an error here
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const appState = useContext(StateContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/api/status/${id}`);
                console.log(res.data);

                if (res.data) {
                    setPostData(res.data);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                } else {
                    setIsLoading(true);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <main className="main-view">
            {isLoading ? (
                'Loading...'
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <div className="main-view__user-feed viewpost">
                        <div className="main-view__user-feed__author viewpost__redone">
                            <div className="viewpost__name">
                                <img
                                    src={postData.avatar}
                                    alt="image tweet"
                                    className="img__viewpost"
                                ></img>
                            </div>
                            <h2 className="viewpost__name__surname">
                                {postData.name} {postData.surname}
                            </h2>
                            <Link
                                to={`/${postData.username}`}
                                className="username__author__viewpost"
                            >
                                @{postData.username}
                            </Link>

                            <a href="#" className="author_post__viewpost">
                                {postData.text}
                            </a>

                            <div className="author__stats">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>{postData.retweet}</span> Retweets
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>{postData.likes}</span> Likes
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>{postData.retweet}</span> Quote Tweets
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="icons__viewpost">
                                <section>
                                    <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                        <Link to="/" className="top-nav__link">
                                            <IcomoonReact
                                                className="top-nav__icon"
                                                iconSet={iconSet}
                                                color="ffffff"
                                                size={20}
                                                icon="bubble2"
                                            />

                                            <span>0</span>
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                </section>

                                <section>
                                    <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                        <a href="#" className="top-nav__link">
                                            <IcomoonReact
                                                className="top-nav__icon"
                                                iconSet={iconSet}
                                                color="ffffff"
                                                size={20}
                                                icon="loop2"
                                            />
                                            <span>3</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </section>

                                <section>
                                    <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                        <Link to="/" className="top-nav__link">
                                            <IcomoonReact
                                                className="top-nav__icon"
                                                iconSet={iconSet}
                                                color="ffffff"
                                                size={20}
                                                icon="heart"
                                            />
                                            <span>2</span>
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                </section>

                                <section>
                                    <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                        <a href="#" className="top-nav__link">
                                            <IcomoonReact
                                                className="top-nav__icon"
                                                iconSet={iconSet}
                                                color="ffffff"
                                                size={20}
                                                icon="books"
                                            />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="main-view__user-tweet viewpost__textarea">
                        <img src={appState.user.avatar} alt="image tweet" />
                        <form action="#" className="main-view__user-tweet__search">
                            <textarea
                                maxlength="250"
                                id="textBox1"
                                name="content"
                                TextMode="MultiLine"
                                className="main-view__user-tweet__input"
                                onkeyup="setHeight('textBox1');"
                                onkeydown="setHeight('textBox1');"
                                placeholder="Tweet your reply"
                            ></textarea>
                        </form>
                        <a href="#" className="main-view__user-tweet__button">
                            Reply
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            {isLoading
                ? 'Loading...'
                : postData.comments.map((comment) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="main-view__user-feed">
                                <img src={comment.avatar} alt="image tweet"></img>
                                <div className="main-view__user-feed__author">
                                    <div className="name">
                                        <h2>
                                            {comment.name} {comment.surname}
                                        </h2>
                                        <Link
                                            to={`/${comment.username}`}
                                            className="username__author"
                                        >
                                            @{comment.username}
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className="reply-p">
                                        Replying to <a href="">@{postData.username}</a>
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="#" className="author_post">
                                        {comment.text}
                                    </a>
                                    <div className="icons">
                                        <section>
                                            <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                                <a href="#" className="top-nav__link">
                                                    <svg className="top-nav__icon">
                                                        <use xlinkHref="img/sprite.svg#icon-bubble2"></use>
                                                    </svg>
                                                    <span>0</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </section>

                                        <section>
                                            <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                                <a href="#" className="top-nav__link">
                                                    <svg className="top-nav__icon">
                                                        <use xlinkHref="img/sprite.svg#icon-loop2"></use>
                                                    </svg>
                                                    <span>0</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </section>

                                        <section>
                                            <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                                <a href="#" className="top-nav__link">
                                                    <svg className="top-nav__icon">
                                                        <use xlinkHref="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart"></use>
                                                    </svg>
                                                    <span>0</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </section>

                                        <section>
                                            <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                                <a href="#" className="top-nav__link">
                                                    <svg className="top-nav__icon">
                                                        <use xlinkHref="img/sprite.svg#icon-books"></use>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                  })}
        </main>
    );
}

export default ViewPost;
```

Comment: its too long code and hard to read can you reduce code size? and make it cleaner

Comment: you could understand what problem is if you look from where the state is declared until I console log the postData.comments.length.

Comment: The whole code is the more detailed version of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Your problem lies where you're reading `postData.comments.length`.  With the way your array is set up you'd instead read `postData[0].comments.length` since it's an array with an object inside of it.  To simplify things, you could correct the initial value:

```js
const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
  _id: '...',
  username: '...',
  avatar: '...',
  date: '...',
  text: '...',
  image: '...',
  likes: [],
  hearts: [],
  retweet: [],
  user: '...',
  isFollowing: 'false',
  isVerified: 'false',
  comments: [{ test: 'test' }],
  name: '...',
  surname: '...',
});
```

Comment: that works now but when the real data comes in, the reiteration at postData[0].comments.map... throws the same errors 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comments')'. (you can see more info at the end .map)

I'm trying to render the default values first, and then the data.

Comment: Hmm, okay.  Which did you decide to do - restructure the `useState` initial value or use `postData[0]`?

Comment: all good now. I added an if check and seems to be working now.